# Android app crashing on real device but working on emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

I am kinda new to programming, and trying to make a project witch is an android app, but when I try to run it on my device it just crashes.

I get these errors in my logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
    2020-07-12 19:52:04.128 12417-12417/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.temperatura, PID: 12417
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
            at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:121)
            at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:98)
            at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:94)
            at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:110)
            at com.example.temperatura.MainActivity.loadIntoListView(MainActivity.java:116)
            at com.example.temperatura.MainActivity.access$200(MainActivity.java:21)
            at com.example.temperatura.MainActivity$1DownloadJSON.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:68)
            at com.example.temperatura.MainActivity$1DownloadJSON.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:52)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:755)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:192)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:772)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7520)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

And this is my main activity.java:

```
package com.example.temperatura;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    List<String> sensor = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
    boolean needRefresh;        // whether refresh is needed


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final SwipeRefreshLayout pullToRefresh = findViewById(R.id.pullToRefresh);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        downloadJSON("http://pillsmanager.com/temperatura/conn_app.php");

        pullToRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                downloadJSON("http://pillsmanager.com/temperatura/conn_app.php");
                pullToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                needRefresh = true;
            }
        });
    }


    private void downloadJSON(final String urlWebService) {

        class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {
                    if (needRefresh) {
                        updateAndLoadIntoListView(s);
                    } else {
                        loadIntoListView(s);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urlWebService);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                    String json;
                    while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(json + "\n");
                    }
                    return sb.toString().trim();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        DownloadJSON getJSON = new DownloadJSON();
        getJSON.execute();

    }

    private void updateAndLoadIntoListView(String json) throws JSONException {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        sensor.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            final JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            sensor.add(obj.getString("temperature") + " " + obj.getString("humidity"));

        }


        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        needRefresh = false;
    }


    private void loadIntoListView(String json) throws JSONException {


        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            final JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            sensor.add(obj.getString("temperature") + " " + obj.getString("humidity"));


        }

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sensor);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    }
}
```

All the help is much appreciated, I have tried everything but I can't figure out the problem

Comment: That stack trace is saying that you're passing null to `loadIntoListView()` from `onPostExecute()`, which means that `doInBackground()` is returning null. It's quite likely that an Exception is being thrown there, but you're ignoring it in the `catch`. You should at least `e.printStackTrace();`, and look in your logs for that.

Comment: Run Emulator normally without installing app. I am sure emulator have some other issue and crash not happening because to your code.

Comment: the emulator is running ok, but when i try to run it on my real device the app just crashes

Comment: @MikeM. what do you mean with that? can you explain it a little bit better pls?

Comment: In the `catch` in `doInBackground()`, you're ignoring the `Exception` there, and just returning null if something goes wrong. To find out what is going wrong there, you should at least add `e.printStackTrace();`, and look for the stack trace in your logs. That should tell you what the specific issue is. I would guess that it's possibly a [cleartext error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45940861).

Comment: i already did the https thing and now the app opens, but it still crashes

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace, it seems that you are passing `null` to `loadIntoListView` method.

It can only happen in your code if you are running into exception with your `doInBackground` method, where you are handling downloading.

There could be many reasons for it to fail on the device and work on the emulator. I recommend switching to some networking library to handle downloads and deal with those edge cases. It can be really annoying. Try using [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/)